# Open stream over https in VLC and wildcard SSL certificate

Tags: vlc-media-player, ssl, https

I am wondering how to trust a certificate manually in VLC.
My purpose is to open a stream over https. gnutls returns an error: the common name of the certificate sent by the remote site is
"*.example.com", 
which does not match
"foo.bar.example.com" (because of the dot).

So I would like to tell VLC that this certificate can be trusted. This can be done easily in Firefox for instance (it offers to add a security exception). How do you do it in VLC ?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this ticket](http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/3101) it looks like this has been broken for a while and still not fixed.  There are also several forum posts covering the topic:

- [vlc 1.1.0 gnutls problem](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=78766)
- [gnutls [SSL] streaming broken?](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=68078&p=228947)